# If a file compression (GZIP) minimizes the size of the file, doesn't it take a time to decompress as well?

Tags: file, size, compression

How should I decide if GZIP will help or slow me?
The offset of compression is decompression time. So, how is compression helpful? So it really come down to choosing small file size versus decompression time?

Answer (score 2):

Your mileage may vary, but for modern systems with modern data rates, gzip is a big win on transmission time vs. decompression time on compressible data, e.g. text, html, xml.  gzip decompression is very fast, about 300 MB/s.

Comment: Thx. But where did u get the data that 300 MB/s decompression time. Source plz

Comment: I timed it.  You can too.

Comment: https://quixdb.github.io/squash-benchmark/ should help give you an idea.  Especially the "Transfer + Processing" chart.  As you can see the results are wildly different depending on the data type and the machine.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this depends on the speed of whatever you are transferring the files over and the cost of doing so.

Then, do people care more about fast downloads or fast execution after downloading.

I think that the size of a gzip archive varies too widely based on the contents of the archive for anybody to make general statement about what you should do here.

Benchmarking is probably the way to go here, see what the effects are. My guess is it won't take long to compress, and the few MBs saved each time are worth it.